# Is it shuffled FizzBuzz?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, fizzbuzz

A twin of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/249186/fix-my-fizzbuzz).

FizzBuzz is where a range of positive integers is taken, and numbers divisible by 3 are replaced with "Fizz", divisible by 5 with "Buzz" and divisible by 15 with "FizzBuzz". For example, FizzBuzz from 1 to 10 is `1, 2, Fizz, 4, Buzz, Fizz, 7, 8, Fizz, Buzz`.

Your challenge is to, given a list of Fizzes, Buzzes, FizzBuzzes and a value representing an integer (I'm going to use Int), determine if it can be arranged into valid FizzBuzz.

For example, `Int, Fizz, Fizz, Buzz` can be arranged into `Fizz, Buzz, Int, Fizz` (for example 9,10,11,12) which is valid. But `Buzz, Fizz, Buzz` cannot, as the two `Buzz` need to be five values apart.

You may choose any four values to represent Fizz, Buzz, FizzBuzz and Int.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

### Truthy

```
Int, Int, Fizz
Fizz, Int, Fizz, Buzz
Fizz, Fizz, Fizz, Int, Int, Int, Buzz
Buzz, Int, Int, Int, Fizz, FizzBuzz
FizzBuzz, Int, Int, Int, Int
```

### Falsy

```
Buzz, FizzBuzz, Fizz
Buzz, Fizz, Buzz
Int, Int, Int
Fizz, Int, Fizz
FizzBuzz, Int, Int, Buzz, Fizz
Int, Int, Fizz, Fizz, Fizz, Buzz, Buzz
```

Comment: Suggested test case: `Int, Int, Fizz, Fizz, Fizz, Buzz, Buzz`.

Comment: @Nitrodon Spent a while figuring out whether that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
L₄+v₍₃₅ÞS?Ṗ↔ḃ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJM4oKEK3bigo3igoPigoXDnlM/4bmW4oaU4biDIiwiIiwiW1swLDBdLFswLDBdLFsxLDBdXSJd) Super slow. Uses `[0,0]` for `Int`, `[1,0]` for `Fizz`, `[0,1]` for `Buzz`, and `[1,1]` for `FizzBuzz`.

[Test cases, using 14 instead of 26 to make it faster.](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJhVCIsIsabYCwgYC9gSW50YGBGaXp6YFwiYEJ1enpgSmBGaXp6QnV6emBKMDBcIjEwZlwiMDFcIndKMTFmd0rEvzvGmyIsIkwxNCt24oKN4oKD4oKFw55TbuG5luKGlOG4gyIsIjsiLCJJbnQsIEludCwgRml6elxuRml6eiwgSW50LCBGaXp6LCBCdXp6XG5GaXp6LCBGaXp6LCBGaXp6LCBJbnQsIEludCwgSW50LCBCdXp6XG5CdXp6LCBJbnQsIEludCwgSW50LCBGaXp6LCBGaXp6QnV6elxuRml6ekJ1enosIEludCwgSW50LCBJbnQsIEludFxuQnV6eiwgRml6ekJ1enosIEZpenpcbkJ1enosIEZpenosIEJ1enpcbkludCwgSW50LCBJbnRcbkZpenosIEludCwgRml6elxuRml6ekJ1enosIEludCwgSW50LCBCdXp6LCBGaXp6Il0=)

```
L₄*v₍₃₅ÞS?Ṗ↔ḃ
L₄+           # Length of input + 26 (14 would be enough, but 26 is one byte)
   v₍₃₅       # For each in range [1, that], calculate [n % 3 == 0, n % 5 == 0]
       ÞS     # All sublists
           ↔  # Keep only lists that are in...
         ?Ṗ   # The permutations of the input
            ḃ # Is this truthy? (does it have at least one element?)
```

Comment: Technically I could make this one byte shorter with ten power instead of plus 26, but that would make it so slow.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 72 bytes

Expects `0` for *Int*, `1` for *Fizz*, `2` for *Buzz*, `3` for *FizzBuzz*. Returns `0` or `1`.

This is the same algorithm as in [my answer to the other challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/249231/58563).

```javascript
f=(a,i=k=15)=>k--&&a.sort().map(_=>++i%3<1|2*!(i%5)).sort()+''==a|f(a,k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7LTsMwEEX3/YqhUmsPSa2mVTcFZ4FEJdZdAkJW6hSTEAfbRaKPbw/OQ6RAN1fzuHPmvolPYROjSjcp9EZWVcqpCBXPeLRAHmeTyXgsmNXGUWTvoqQvPA4CNZrfRsfZ9RVVowVitw8I4VwcUw/IsDLyY6eMpCS1BJmRYrNSuVx/FQmdInN67Ywqtp5qy1w5OnwqhshSbe5F8kot8BgOA4BcOhDAwXY2EgJpgzQWengo3BKmIazUfr@EKIS7XV3M2knbzE/4aJ/xxvMSXVidS5brLfVB0Q9PWHlICI3UR4NazvqW2U3PtT9rpHHV8m/TH/2QLvq8dIDe0iTqy@7N75s/gS8@6BHf)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (             // f is a recursive function taking:
  a,              //   a[] = input array
  i =             //   i = index in the FizzBuzz sequence
  k = 15          //   k = counter
) =>              //
  k-- &&          // decrement k; abort if it was 0
  a.sort()        // normalize a[] by sorting it in lexicographical order
  .map(_ =>       // for each value in a[]:
    ++i % 3 < 1 | //   generate the FizzBuzz sequence,
    2 * !(i % 5)  //   starting at i + 1
  )               // end of map()
  .sort()         // normalize this new array
  + '' == a |     // coerce it to a string and compare it with a[]
  f(a, k)         // recursive call with i set to the new value of k
```

Comment: [70](https://tio.run/##bY/LTsMwEEX3/YqhUmsPSa2mVTcFZ4FEJdZdAkJW6hSjYAfbRaKPbw/OQ6RAN1eemXvPjN/Ep3CZVaWfaLORVZVzKmLFkwXyVE0m43Fe13gUzBnrKbJ3UdIXnkaRGs1vk@Ps@oqq0QKxm0eEcC4qKz92ykpKckeQWSk2K1XI9ZfO6BSZN2tvld4GnCsL5enwSQ@R5cbei@yVOuApHAYAhfQggIPrbCQG0l7QWOjhQfslTGNYqf1@CUkMd7v6MWs7bTE/4aN7xpvAy4x2ppCsMFsa/oWhecIqQGJopA4NajmrW2bXPdc@1kjjquXfpA/9kC76gnSA3tJc1D@7Nb8zfw6@uKBHfAM)

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 213 bytes:

```py
def v(r,l,k=[]):
 if not r:yield k
 for i,a in enumerate(l):
  if r[0]%(a|1)<1:yield from v(r[1:],l[:i]+l[i+1:],k+[a])
def f(l,c=0):
 while(c:=c+1)<sum(i**2for i in l):
  if next(v(range(c,c+len(l)),l),0):return 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/dasMgGL3PU3w3A61e6KQwpHkS8UJSXSXGBGfWFvbuma5d12aFc@P5/ZzO@TBG8TalZdlbB58o0UD7VmksG/AO4pghybO3YQ99A25M4KkBH8HGebDJZItC9VZzUky/IPPF8Y5fMy6NQ21VXGoalPSaBOVJffVEGY2bOutQoF3Las/x4INFnWw7Umo@5gH5zeb1Z7eu3raiPWVUik18L3bakWBjuQTTgGkpSjbPKQJfpuRjRg4pRqFAaIybGycuHIXtmr6A/eJR394pxcUfVX4vs3WwqmJN/rvgWVg8@cDf1rV2@QY)

Comment: @Steffan Updated

Comment: [216](https://tio.run/##bU9Na8MgGL7nV7yXgVYPOikMWf7GLuJBUl0lxgRn1hb23zNdu67NCs/F5/N1OuX9GMXLlJZlZx18okQD7VulsWzAO4hjhiRP3oYd9A24MYGnBnwEG@fBJpMtCtVbzUkx/YTMF8ev/JJxaRxqq@JS06Ck1yQoT@qrJ8po3NRZhwLtWlZ7DnsfLOpk25FS8zEPyG82zz@7dfW69SbbaI8ZlW4T30uCdiTYWI7BNGBaupLNc4rAlyn5mJFDilEoEBrj5sqJM0dhu6bPYL@417c3SnHxe5XfymwdrKpYk/8ueBQWDz7wt3WpXb4B) with looser I/O plus other golfs

Comment: Down to 206 by outputting by error/no error: (requires Python 3.9) https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVLLasMwEKRXf8USKEixCnZNoIj62i8ovQhRhLNKhBU5KHKbQP-kl1zaz-m9_ZpKdUIeDexBmpmd2RV6_1xuwrxz2-1HH_TN3ffXFDW8EM8sa2shKc_AaHBdAM83Bu0U2gx058EwBcYBun6BXgUkNmmT2ItCXhP1VtL7ctejfbdIrqLkklnBjcytMHm6tblQkmYpdkYsa-oi-bzOjUXS8LrJo82qXxAzHt_-5abUmDV6HoknXjtcBxKdlZtFPWtyiy6OQpmlrKBy2Ornapz8NVHJO_gNn8VjBrhucBm4x9B7B4--x4jZFe6RBxUv2dIbF4gmomAQq5KUHrBqwBhMzuGhin2d8pMjJqrKU7Y8povzxsRW5-C_CS41VxcWOGTtbIcn23-IXw

Comment: Off of pxegers, you can also remoev the `V:=`

Comment: @Steffan Thanks, updated

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
g°L35SδÖŒεœ€Q}à
```

Inputs as Int=`[0,0]`; Fizz=`[1,0]`; Buzz=`[0,1]`; FizzBuzz=`[1,1]`.
Too slow to output anything on TIO..

[(Don't) try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8//dAGH2PT4HNbDk87Ounc1qOTHzWtCaw9vOD//@hoAx2DWB0oaQgkYwE)
[Try a modified version online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOTj7Fp8Lkth6cdnaR3bsrRyY@a1gQeXvD/f3S0gY5BrA6UNASSsQA), with: hard-coded 26 `₂` instead of `g°`; find_first `.Δ` instead of `ε...}`; outputs the first found list, or -1 if falsey (which still times out for falsey or too long test cases.. -_-).

**Explanation:**

```python
g             # Push the input-length
 °            # 10 to the power this length
  L           # Pop and push a list in the range [1,10**length]
   35S        # Push pair [3,5]
      δ       # Map over the [1,10**length]-list, with [3,5] as argument for each:
       Ö      #  Check if the current integer is divible by [3,5]
        Œ     # Get all sublists of this
         ε    # Map over each sublist:
          œ   #  Get all permutations of it
           €  #  Map over each permutation:
            Q #   Check if it's equal to the (implicit) input-list
         }    # Close the sublists-map
          à   # Flattened maximum to check if any inner permutation was truthy
              # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 109 bytes

```python
lambda n:sorted(n)in[sorted([max(a for a in[1,3,5,15]if j%a<1)for j in range(i,i+len(n))])for i in range(15)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU@xTsMwEN39FSdVqLHwYkWWUEoHGCqQmEoZUPBgVKe4Sp3IMRL058PZaXGqwHJ@797d87v22380Nr9pXV8t3/paHd63CmzRNc7rbWapseUJlwf1lSmoGgcKsM1ZzgTjQpoK9lfqltMg7VECp@xOZ4aZ61pbNKEyaiZpXFDZz2CtW6c7bb3yprFdQWbAYQmP1uuddshyZCtzPCIUCO8/I@Ti1I6c4DhyviChhShfkCAgEkPvxDhS0jpjfTbfrF82D6/FnBISotUhWlmiE4NYwppkpAzvqMVihCSMa1qO5TwY3omY9sZ@f45ikbKAIXeV1ZT@HrG6e3qe3DCYJLvzJYmlbJe/TM/9L9jI@TJa/wM)

Takes `Int` as `1`, `Fizz` as `3`, `Buzz` as `5`, `FizzBuzz` as `15`.

### Explanation

One key observation is that, if we replace all the integers with a single value `Int`, then the FizzBuzz sequence has a period of 15:

```python
Int
Int
Fizz
Int
Buzz
Fizz
Int
Int
Fizz
Buzz
Int
Fizz
Int
Int
FizzBuzz
```

It is rather easy to prove that this is in fact the case. *Hint: start by placing the multiples of 3 and 5.*

What we can therefore do is focus on the first 15 numbers. From each of these numbers, we can make a little subsequence of numbers whose length is the same as the length of the input, and determine whether the sorted values (where the integers become `Int`) are the same as the input.

How do we do this? We use a cool trick whereby we get the maximum number out of `[1, 3, 5, 15]` such that the current number is divisible by that number. Since `Int` is `1`, all numbers that are not multiples of 3 or 5 correspond to `Int`. Multiples of 3 but not of 5 correspond to `Fizz`, etc. We can eventually generate this sequence of 1s, 3s, 5s and 15s.

Sorting the input and comparing it against the sorted values of the subsequence will reveal whether the input is shuffled FizzBuzz or not.

*Yay! First answer in... what, two months?*

Comment: Why 3.8 and why prerelease?

Comment: @TheShwarma It's a TIO thing

Comment: but what's TIO?

Comment: @TheShwarma Try It Online, the website that a lot of us use to run code. It's convenient because we can use just about any major programming language on it without any local installation, and we can share a link to our code as well. Unfortunately, TIO hasn't updated Python to the latest version. It's still stuck on the prerelease version of 3.8.